# UITabBarController: Tab bar covers view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am fairly new to UI elements in iOS (all of my apps were Gl games) but I'm trying it out and I found myself in a bit of a pickle...

The view controller for the bulk of my app is a subclass of UITabBarController and I have a few tabs with (currently empty) child view controllers. For the most part I have these working fine, but my problem is with correctly sizing and placing items inside of a tabbed view controller. If, for instance, I try to place something just above the tab bar, then I can't just set the Y position to the height of the the child view controller's view minus the height of the object I'm placing. I also need to account for the tab bar itself.

I can see that part of my problem is that I'm simply creating the view controller and not telling it what size it's view needs to be. Is there a function provided to me to calculate the height the view needs to be? I could just figure out the height of the bar and subtract that from the overall height, but that just feels to flimsy to me.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I am doing it all programmatically and I don't intend to use Interface Builder. My main concern with the view size is making sure that things like table views fit snugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Interface Builder and auto layout, you can place `UIView` items on your `UIViewController` and if you set a size constraint on the view you're placing you can also set position constraints that are relative to screen edge or adjacent views, in your case `UITabBar`.

Comment: I'm not using interface builder. I'm doing it all programmatically.

Comment: then I believe you should check out this doc (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html).  Personally I find it much easier to configure certain interface attributes using Interface Builder, but I can understand why you would want to do it all programmatically.